# Having trouble in Implementing Sprakle.Framework in Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

I am very new to Cocoa Applications. Please forgive me ignorances.

Please allow me elaborate what I am doing.

1. I have downloaded the SPARKLE.framework from this link:[Sparkle](http://sparkle-project.org/)
2. I Dragged and Dropped the SPARKLE in my project

[image]

3. Then I added it in Embedded Binaries

[image]

4. Created an object of SUUpdater in MainMenu.xib

[image]

5. Then I changed the project verison to 1.2 and arcived>>zip then uploaded it to the server.
6. Then I created a appcast (xml) and uploaded it to the server and added a key (SUFeedURL) in project info.plist with the url of the appcast xml

here is the appcast url: [appcast](http://techheal.in/mac/File.xml)
[image]

7. I changed the project version back to 1.0 and run the applicaiton. Its not asking for the update.

Comment: What do you see in the system log? Is the application sandboxed?

Comment: where can I see the system log? Applicaiton is made to be run on any macbook . Is the proecess that I have mentioned above it right?

Comment: did you add it to target -> build phases -> Link Binary with Libraries?

Comment: yes @dan, I have added the sparkel.framework there. Sorry for not mentioning it in question

Comment: Do you see any Sparkle output in the Xcode output log?

Comment: @Aderstedt here us what I am getting : 
 Unknown class 'SUUpdater', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /Users/Paxcel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TechHeal-dalqofyfskcrfzgkqbajthofljwe/Build/Products/Debug/TechHeal.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/MainMenu.nib.

Comment: Did you link properly to Sparkle.framework?

Answer (score 0):

Your appcast contains `sparkle:version="1.2"`, which is not a value that can be directly compared to `CFBundleVersion`. Use only integers for `sparkle:version` and `CFBundleVersion`.